# Transform Blazor component to RenderFragment

Tags: blazor, components

I need to change instance of a Blazor component into `RenderFragment`. I was able to achieve it with the use of reflection:

```
public static RenderFragment CreateRenderFragmentFromInstance(this IComponent instance, IComponent namespaceComponent)
{
    int attributeNumber = 0;

    return builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenComponent(attributeNumber++, instance.GetType());

        var properties = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(EventCallback))
            {
                var originalCallback = (EventCallback)property.GetValue(instance)!;

                var wrappedCallback = EventCallback.Factory.Create(namespaceComponent, async arg =>
                {
                    if (originalCallback.HasDelegate)
                    {
                        await originalCallback.InvokeAsync(arg);
                    }
                });

                builder.AddAttribute(attributeNumber++, property.Name, wrappedCallback);
            }
            else
            {
                builder.AddAttribute(attributeNumber++, property.Name, property.GetValue(instance));
            }
        }

        builder.CloseComponent();
    };
}
```

**But is there a simpler way how to do this ?**

For example with some strange combination of builder-tree methods ?

---

**Usecase:**

**Intro:**

I have created a simple [Blazor popup library](https://github.com/Kebechet/Blazor.Components.Popup). Usage steps:

- You download my nuget: `Kebechet.Blazor.Components.Popup`,
- install service to DI: `builder.Services.AddPopupWrapperServices();`
- put `<PopupWrapper />` component into your `MainLayout.razor`
- in your page just `@inject PopupWrapperService _popupWrapperService`

and call it like:

```
var isSuccess =  await _popupWrapperService.Show(new YesNoPopup(), this);
if (isSuccess is null)
{
    // user closed the popup
}
```

as you can see I create instance of a new object `YesNoPopup` in the argument. This `YesNoPopup` is component implementing `IPopupable` and thus can simply return value to the service using it.

This way of creating popups in-code instead of specifying HTML/creating component in `.razor` is for me the most elegant and most easily to use.

**Problematic Part**

When I call the `Show` method with component as one of the inputs it calls [this method](https://github.com/Kebechet/Blazor.Components.Popup/blob/main/src/Blazor.Components.Popup/Services/PopupWrapperService.cs#L27-#L56). In the method I want to [create `RenderFragment` from the component](https://github.com/Kebechet/Blazor.Components.Popup/blob/main/src/Blazor.Components.Popup/Services/PopupWrapperService.cs#L36) so I can then render it into `PopupWrapper.razor` with [`_currentPopupWrapper.RenderPopupContent(renderFragment);`](https://github.com/Kebechet/Blazor.Components.Popup/blob/main/src/Blazor.Components.Popup/Services/PopupWrapperService.cs#L37).

I thought that there should be some method in treeBuilder like `.AddComponent` and not just `OpenComponent`. So that is basically the point of my question. If it is possible to do also without using my reflection approach.

Comment: What kind of usage?  The repo doesn't help much.  Add a use-case.

Comment: You can define a render fragment like this `RenderFragment someContent = @<div>this is my content </div>;` in your `@code` section in any blazor component.

Comment: @Marius thanks, I found this out just recently but in my usecase I need to do this inside function where I have IComponent input and from that I unfortunatelly cant do `@<IComponent />`

Comment: You can declare your `ChildContent` in this manner and pass the parameter to your component's declaration.  I would suggest you add some reproducible code or assumed/simplified code so that we can better assist. This will also help other users of the platform with the same usecase.

Comment: @Marius I have added extra clarification of the usage

Answer (score 0):

I prefer much simpler approaches to these types of components, and also a preference on using Blazor in it's standard approach which helps with readability and understanding.

Therefor I recommend you change your approach to a more standard one by following this example implementation:

### `PopUpWrapper.razor`

```
@inject PopUpService PopUpService

@* Render notifications in the service  *@
@if (PopUpService.Popups?.Count > 0)
{
    @foreach (var popup in PopUpService.Popups)
    {
        <div class="PopupContainer">
            <h1>@popup.Heading</h1>
            <div class="PopupContent">
                @switch (popup.Type)
                {
                    case PopupType.YesNo:
                        <PopupContent_YesNo OnCallback="@popup.OnCallback" Message="@popup.Message" />
                        break;
                    case PopupType.Alert:
                        <PopupContent_Alert OnCallback="@popup.OnCallback" Message="@popup.Message" />
                        break; 
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        //Register the service to be able to update the state of the container
        PopUpService.RegisterLayout(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}
```

### `PopupContent_YesNo.razor`

```
<div>
    <p>@Message</p>
    <button @onclick="async () => await OnCallback.InvokeAsync(true)">Yes</button>
    <button @onclick="async () => await OnCallback.InvokeAsync(false)">No</button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public EventCallback<bool> OnCallback { get; set; }
}
```

### `PopupContent_Alert.razor`

```
<div>
    <p>@Message</p>
    <button @onclick="async () => await OnCallback.InvokeAsync(true)">OK</button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public EventCallback<bool> OnCallback { get; set; }
}
```

### `PopupType.cs`

```
    //Determines the popup to render
    public enum PopupType {
        YesNo,
        Alert
    }
```

### `Popup.cs`

```
//Class with default constructor for linking to the service
//You can extend the constructor to populate the properties by parameters
public class PopUp(PopUpService service)
{
    PopUpService _popupService = service;

    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public PopupType Type { get; set; }
    public Action<bool> ActionCallback { get; set; }

    //The callback, will also remove the popup
    public void OnCallback(bool response)
    {
        _popupService.Popups.Remove(this);

        ActionCallback(response);
    }
}
```

### `PopUpService.cs`

```
public class PopUpService : IDisposable
{
    //All popups go in here
    public List<PopUp> Popups { get; private set; } = new();

    //State change trigger
    Action OnStateChange { get; set; }

    public void RegisterLayout(Action stateChange)
    {
        //Registering state change
        OnStateChange = stateChange;
    }

    //Simple standard popup, can extend with RenderFragment for customization
    public void Show(PopupType type, string heading, string message, Action<bool> actionCallback)
    {
        Popups.Add(new PopUp(this) { Type = type, Heading = heading, Message = message, ActionCallback = actionCallback });
        OnStateChange.Invoke();
    }

    //Remove popup, called from PopUp class
    public void RemovePopup(PopUp popup)
    {
        Popups.Remove(popup);
        OnStateChange.Invoke();
    }

    //Dispose if closed
    public void Dispose()
    {
        OnStateChange = delegate { };
    }
}
```

Add `<PopupWrapper />` somewhere on a `Layout` like `MainLayout.cs`

### `Index.razor` Example:

```
@inject PopUpService PopUpService
@page "/"

<button @onclick="@(() => OpenYesNo())">
    Add Yes No
</button>

<button @onclick="@(() => OpenOK())">
    Add OK
</button>

@code {
    int popupCounter = 0;

    void OpenYesNo()
    {
        PopUpService.Show(PopupType.YesNo,
            $"{popupCounter++}: This is a yes no",
            "This is the message for a Yes No",
            (r) => Console.WriteLine($"YesNo Result: {r}"));
    }

    void OpenOK()
    {
        PopUpService.Show(PopupType.Alert,
            $"{popupCounter++}: This is an OK",
            "This is the message for an OK",
            (r) => Console.WriteLine($"OK Result: {r}"));
    }
}
```

If you want to extend the functionality you can always change the `Message` and/or `Heading` parameters from a `string` to a `RenderFragment` type.

### Want a RenderFragment instead of strings?

An example implementation could be something like:

```
PopUpService.Show(PopupType.Alert,
            $"{popupCounter++}: This is an OK",
            @<div>This is the message for an OK</div>,
            (r) => Console.WriteLine($"OK Result: {r}"));
```

You can also forego the buttons on the components and add them to the message `RenderFragment`. This is very flexible, but the foundations of showing and hiding the popups will stay relatively the same.

Comment: my goal was to have it as abstract as possible. In my solution I can put any component as an input and it will be rendered in modal. So even though I appreciate the help, it didnt help much. Lets say I prefer more solutions that require less code for using/adjusting them.

Comment: That can easily be extended by updating the content to accept a `RenderFragment`. Change  `Message` from a `string` to a `RenderFragment`.

Comment: @Kebechet, I will extend my answer.

Comment: @Kebechet, the answer has been updated.